# Calling multiple perl scripts over APACHE server?

Tags: javascript, html, perl, apache, cgi

I am pretty new to creating web applications, so I am very unfamiliar with working over a web server. Just to let everyone know, I am implementing html, javascript, strawberry perl, AJAX, and running over an APACHE 2 web server.  I finally have my web app working, I have an html file that calls a perl script that is in my htdocs directory. Here is a mock up of my .html file for reference, this one simply alerts the user of the output printed by the perl script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>


function loadXMLDoc() {
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
var str;
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
// Get output from perl script and print it
str = xmlhttp.responseText;
alert(str);
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/try.pl" , false); //perl script
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Example</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Display</button>

</body>
</html>
```

So this file test.html calls a perl script [try.pl] within the same directory. Also, the perl script just prints a number so this alerts the user of the number. This is just an example of my implementation. My actual perl script and java script [inside the ready state block] is much more complicated. Now I have to add functionality to my web app, so to my questions:

1. I am looking to run a second and separate perl script when a different event happens. For example, when a button is clicked this perl script is being ran. I am going to have another different event, say a double click on an icon or something, that will need to call this second perl script. Will I simply have the new event call a different function [the first is called Loadxmldoc()] that is almost identical to the one I have here except it will have different code in the ready state block and call a different perl script at the end of it? I am a little confused as to how to implement this.
2. Also, If I have a list of file names within my javascript code, I need to process EACH of the files using a perl script.  Currently I am only processing one so calling the perl script as I have here is fine. I have looked all over the internet to try to find how I would do this but it seems every explanation just covers how to call "a" CGI script. So within my code, say where I am "alerting" the user, I am going to have an array that stores the file names. I need to iterate over this array and for each filename [array element] I need to call the same perl script to process that file. How should I go about implementing this? Currently, my html file is only calling the perl script once and I do not know how I could call it for EACH file since my GET command is outside of my ready state block...

Any help or direction would be appreciated. I am expected to deliver soon and have been spending way too much time sifting through repetitive examples that haven't helped me...:/

Answer (score 0):

As far as generalizing your AJAX request, you can create a function (or rather, a set of functions) that would process different types of responses, as follows:

```
var requests = [];
requests['script1'] = "http://localhost/try.pl";
requests['script2'] = "http://localhost/try2.pl";
var response_processing = [];
response_processing['script1'] = function (xmlhttp) {
    var str = xmlhttp.responseText;
    alert(str);
};
// Here, you can add more functions to do response processing for other AJAX calls, 
under different map keys.
```

Now, in your AJAX code, you call an appropriate request AND appropriate response processor, based on your script name (passed to `loadXMLDoc()` call as follows): `loadXMLDoc("script1");`

```
function loadXMLDoc(script_name) {

    // Your generic AJAX code as you already implemented

    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        response_processing[script_name](xmlhttp);
        // Careful so script_name doesn't get closured in onreadystatechange()
    }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", requests[script_name], false); //perl script
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```